# How to extract multi-layer nested compressed files of multi format

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have some multi-layer organized compressed files, which are compressed in different methods. A sample structure looks like this (non compressed data files are omitted for simplicity).

```
A.zip
  |---B.zip
  |     |-----C.zip
  |---C.rar
  |---D.tar.gz
```

How can I extract all files into a new folder and keep this structure unchanged? I have searched and get something like `find . -depth -name '*.zip' -exec /usr/bin/unzip -n {} \; -exec rm {} \;`, but it only can uncompress `*.zip`.

Comment: Beware zip bombs such as 42.zip (http://www.unforgettable.dk/) or quines (https://alf.nu/ZipQuine).

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for this interesting and useful advice. But the whole zip file won't exceed 1M and is not self-containing.

Comment: Do you want to delete or keep the archives after unpacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that pattern, once for each file type:

```
find . -depth -name '*.zip' -exec unzip -n {} \; -delete
find . -depth -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar zxf {} \; -delete
find . -depth -name '*.rar' -exec unrar x {} \; -delete
```

Granted, this solution traverses the target path as many times as you have file types, but it has the benefit that it's simple.

You could use a single `find` to process all file types, but readability will suffer a bit:

```
find . -depth \( -name '*.zip' -exec unzip -n {} \; -delete \) \
           -o \( -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar zxf {} \; -delete \) \
           -o \( -name '*.rar' -exec unrar x {} \; -delete \)
```